# how to keep the order of messages,transformed from jms consumer to file in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I want to send some data from database to a queue and then consume data from queue and transform them to another database. but I need to be sure that data is transferring to the second database just in order they have been fetched from the first database. every data row in database has a unique id.

Comment: Care to share with us from which Database the data is coming from and going to ? Might help us help you.

Comment: If you are using Pentaho on both sides, why not go straight from database to database? That will make it easy to maintain the order. If that's not possible, you will have to either rely on the queue order, or sort again on the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the receiving table a little bit, an easy implementation would be to add a TimeStamp field.
When inserting a row into the Queue, each row will have their own TimeStamp.

Depending on the database, you could create a trigger for when a row is inserted, add a TimeStamp code, this way you know exactly when this row was loaded in.

I think this is much more a DATABASE question rather than a PDI question.